# Browser extension / userscript that can remember the YouTube video speed I have set

Tags: video, youtube

I sometimes wants to watch the videos of a YouTube playlists at x2 speed. Whenever I change the speed of a video to x2 (or any other speed), when the next video starts YouTube plays it at x1.

I am looking for a browser extension / userscript that can remember the video speed I have set up and apply it to all next videos YouTube will play.

Answer (score 2):

[YoutubeDefaultSpeed](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/13807-youtubedefaultspeed) on GreasyFork works great for me. You can set a default speed using the radio boxes and it will remember the speed when opening new videos. Below is an image of the radio buttons it adds.

[image: YoutubeDefaultSpeed]